# Linq to Compare two datatables and Filter data

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, datatable

I have two  dataTables ,

```
     Id     Name
      1     Alex
      2     Hiro
```

and my second datatable is

```
      Field   |  1   |  1_Value  |  2     |  2_Value
      Salary  | 123.4|  Good     |  245   |  Bad
      CTC     | 25.4 |  Bad      |  300   |  good
```

First Table Id values 1, 2 are  the column of second table.
I wanna compare both table using the Id - column relation  using linq and my expected filtered output should look like

```
      [{
        "Id" : 1 , "Name": "Alex",
         "data" : [123.4, 25.4] ,"values":["Good" ,"Bad"]},
        {
        "Id" : 2 , "Name": "Hiro",
         "data" : [245, 300] ,"values":["Bad","Good" ]}
        ]
```

My Code try is using foreach loops like

```
        if (ds.Tables[1].Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    var comparisonDetail = (from DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[1].Rows
                                            select new cls.MyBaseClass()
                                            {
                                                ID = Convert.ToInt64(dataRow["ID"]),
                                                Name= Convert.ToString(dataRow["Name"])  
                                            }

                                            ).ToList();
                    foreach (var vId  in  comparisonDetail)
                    {
                       foreach(var vRow in ds.Tables[2].Rows)
                       {
            vId.Data = vRow.value.

                       } 
                    }
```

How can I acheive this using c# linq?
Help would be appreciated

Comment: Why do you shape the second data table like that? You should first try to create a more normalized data structure.

Comment: DataSets and DatTables support relations, which means you don't really need to do anything special to join two related tables. The second table though looks to be pivoted, which makes it essentially unusable. If its original source is some "EmployeeData" table with Salary, CTC fields, just load *this* table, and create a foreign key relation between them

Answer (score 0):

You want to use join ([join clause (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx))

```
using(var c = DataBaseConnection())
{
 var data=from r in c.firstTable
          join st in c.SecondTable on r.Id equals st.FieldId
          select new
                 { 
                   // create return object
                 };
}
```

Comment: This is probably impossible. The OP's second table is denormalized (looks like a pivoted table, or rather, two) with two *columns* per employee, which mean that there are no fixed fields to join

Comment: When I try to put join between two tables, it throws an error  " Could not find the implementation query pattern  for sourcetype System.Data.datatble. 'Join' not found"

Comment: Could you post structure of your tables (without data, just structure)?